# TLabel.AutoSize not working when Label.Align = alTop

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, tlabel

In a Delphi 10.4.2 32-bit Delphi VCL Application, I have a `TLabel` set on top of a `TCard`:

```
object lblColorTransparencyInfo: TLabel
  AlignWithMargins = True
  Left = 5
  Top = 37
  Width = 156
  Height = 20
  Margins.Left = 5
  Margins.Top = 5
  Margins.Right = 5
  Margins.Bottom = 5
  Align = alTop
  Caption = 
    'Pick a color in the image to make that color transparent in the ' +
    'whole image'
  Color = clInfoBk
  ParentColor = False
  Transparent = False
  WordWrap = True
  ExplicitTop = 0
end
```

`Label.Color` is set to `clInfoBk`, so you can visually check the Label's size.

However, despite the `Label.AutoSize` is set to `True`, the Label's HEIGHT is much higher than its text height, despite `Label.AutoSize = True`:

[image]

Is this a bug in `TLabel.AutoSize`?

How can I set the Label Height to its correct text-height? (Please note that the Label's width could dynamically change during run-time which would also dynamically change the text-height at run-time).

Comment: Actually, `AutoSize` partly works for me even with `alTop`. Try to change the `Caption` (a lot: 5 rows, 2 rows, 7 rows, ...) using the OI. But if the container is resized, the height isn't updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "partly"? - I have now changed it to more text but the Label height has increased even more: https://i.imgur.com/FoI4S7R.png

Comment: If I set a label to `Align = alTop`, `WordWrap = True`, and `AutoSize = True` and change the `Caption`, the height is correctly updated: https://privat.rejbrand.se/autosizelabeltop.gif However, resizing the container doesn't update the label's height correctly: https://privat.rejbrand.se/autosizelabelresize.gif

Comment: In any case, this isn't a bug in `AutoSize`, since the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomLabel.AutoSize) says "When AutoSize is True, the size of the label readjusts whenever the text changes. The size of the label is also readjusts [sic!] when the Font property changes."

Comment: Despite `Label.AutoSize = True` I can resize it with the mouse at design-time: https://i.imgur.com/uHLWWsR.gif Do you update `Label.Caption` at run-time?

Comment: No, I used the Object Inspector at design time. Yes, but if you change the `Caption`, doesn't its height autofit?

Comment: With an interposer class and `procedure TLabel.Resize;
begin
  inherited;
  AdjustBounds;
end;` I can make it almost work. Quick and dirty: https://privat.rejbrand.se/autosizelabelresize2.gif

Comment: Just to answer your previous question: When I change the Label.Caption at design-time then it auto-fits perfectly. But at RUN-TIME, the Label.Height stays always the same: https://i.imgur.com/0RZA3FT.gif

Comment: But in that GIF you don't change the `Caption`, but the container size. And that indeed doesn't work, as I wrote in my first comment. And in my comment 6 mins ago, I offered a solution to that issue. (Note: The "caption" is the text.)

Comment: In fact, this has been observed before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105663/resizing-label-does-not-change-label-height?rq=1

Comment: But in your last gif you even also update the container width at run-time. Will try the interposer trick.

Comment: Yes. If I resize the container without the interposer trick, the height isn't updated. The purpose of the interposer trick is to change that. In my third comment I show that it doesn't work by default (https://privat.rejbrand.se/autosizelabelresize.gif) and in my last comment I show that it does work with the interposer: https://privat.rejbrand.se/autosizelabelresize2.gif

Comment: Now I have implemented the interposer trick: https://i.imgur.com/s8QV1Vj.png Is that correct? Btw, now it works, i.e. the height is correctly updated at run-time. Please write that in an answer, so I can accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is taken from the documentation for the [`TCustomLabel.AutoSize`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomLabel.AutoSize) property:

> When AutoSize is False, the label is fixed in size. When AutoSize is True, the size of the label readjusts whenever the text changes. The size of the label is also readjusts [sic] when the Font property changes.
>
> When WordWrap is True, the width of the label is fixed. If AutoSize is also True, changes to the text cause the label to change in height. When AutoSize is True and WordWrap is False, the font determines the height of the label, and changes to the text cause the label to change in width.

It only promises to change the size when the text or font is changed -- not when the label is resized due to its parent being resized. So one could argue that there is no bug here:

[image: Screen recording of alTop label resizing due to its caption being changed.]

[image: Screen recording of alTop label failing to resize due to parent resizing.]

But in any case, one very quick and dirty solution is to tell the label to autosize when it is resized. Using an interposer class,

```pascal
type
  TLabel = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TLabel)
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TLabel }

procedure TLabel.Resize;
begin
  inherited;
  AdjustBounds;
end;
```

we can make it work (almost):

[image: alTop label autosizing when the parent is resized]

Of course, you could make your own `TLabelEx` control with this addition so you can use it as easily as the standard label.

Comment: What do you mean by "almost"?

Comment: You can see that the label's width is also autofitted: the yellow background ends where the text ends, and not at the desired margin. Of course, this is only visible because we have changed the background from transparent to yellow. By default, a label is transparent.

Comment: Could that lead to adding a `Padding` property to `TLabel`? Because that is one of the big shortcomings of `TLabel`: Not having a `Padding` property.

Comment: It wouldn't be difficult for Embarcadero to add more properties to the label control. For now, if you need padding, you can use margins instead or the parent's padding. (And make sure the parent has the right bg colour.)

Comment: Yes, I can have FAKE PADDING by putting the Label on a `TPanel` with the same color, setting the Panel's `AutoSize = True` and the Label's `AlignWithMargins = True`. But it would be nice if `TLabel` had a `Padding` property.

Comment: I wish Embarcadero had you as Chief Developer!

Comment: I have added a small modification to avoid side-effects with "normal" Labels in an existing complex VCL Application: https://i.imgur.com/NJYhskb.png This restricts the interposer modification to Labels with an explicit `Tag`.

Comment: @user1580348: Yes, that is a common way to quickly restrict a modification to only some objects. The proper way, of course, it to create a new control and register it so it ends up in the Component Palette.

Comment: If I make more modifications to `TLabel` then I will create a new component.